# Why is my script not working?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I simply copy-pasted the code from the link given below

http://formvalidation.io/examples/contact-form/

My code just displays the HTML and CSS but it does not support any kind of validation. Captcha is also changing on refreshing page but why does it not validate the form?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/ecmascript"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  </head>
<body>
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone number</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email address</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="7"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" id="captchaOperation"></label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Generate a simple captcha
    function randomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    function generateCaptcha() {
        $('#captchaOperation').html([randomNumber(1, 100), '+', randomNumber(1, 200), '='].join(' '));
    }

    generateCaptcha();

    $('#contactForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                firstName: {
                    row: '.col-xs-4',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The first name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                lastName: {
                    row: '.col-xs-4',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The last name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                phoneNumber: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The phone number is required'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            message: 'The phone number can only contain the digits, spaces, -, (, ), + and .',
                            regexp: /^[0-9\s\-()+\.]+$/
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email address is required'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                        }
                    }
                },
                message: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The message is required'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 700,
                            message: 'The message must be less than 700 characters long'
                        }
                    }
                },
                captcha: {
                    validators: {
                        callback: {
                            message: 'Wrong answer',
                            callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                                var items = $('#captchaOperation').html().split(' '),
                                    sum   = parseInt(items[0]) + parseInt(items[2]);
                                return value == sum;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('err.form.fv', function(e) {
            // Regenerate the captcha
            generateCaptcha();
        });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included formValidation js as you are using formValidation plugin?

Comment: Assuming that `bootstrap.min.js` is the stock version of Twitter Bootstrap, you haven't included the form validation script anywhere.

Comment: how can i include that plugin?

Comment: http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js. Try including this as CDN once.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing not only bootstrap but also the formvalidation scripts and stylesheets.

Try replacing your linked css and js files with these lines:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/ecmascript"></script>

<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css">
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Cool !
Superb !
Thankss !